# escape quotes in sed substitution

Tags: regex, sed

I am attempting to output escaped quotes in a sed substitution like

```
stuff='something=something_else'
var='new_value'
echo ${stuff} | sed "s/something=\S*/something_new=\\\"${var}\\\"/g"
```

I would expect

```
something_new=\"new_value\"
```

but I am getting

```
something_new="new_value"
```

why are my quotes not escaped?

Comment: Double escape for shell, another double escape for sed.

Answer (score 1):

Replace both `\\\` with `\\\\\` in your command.

Answer (score 0):

Don't enclose a whole script in double quotes as you're exposing it to the shell for interpretation and making your life harder, as you've just discovered. Always use single quotes around scripts and only expose any variables that you want the shell to expand by ending the single quotes, double-quoting your variable, and then restarting the single quotes:

```
$ echo "$stuff" | sed 's/something=\S*/something_new=\\"'"$var"'\\"/g'
something_new=\"new_value\"
```

That way, among other benefits, you don't have to add extra escapes to stop the shell from interpreting the rest of the script that you inadvertently exposed to the shell to interpret!